# How to get mobilesdk_app_id parameter in google-services.json for Android projects?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

At the following page:
https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Sign-In

You can create a new project and add services to it. This website will automatically generate a google-services.json file for your new project.

My question is, inside this google-services.json file, how can we retrieve the value for the parameter **mobilesdk_app_id** ? Is it possible to manually find this value? Can't seem to find it in google developer console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this documentation [Processing the JSON File](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin?hl=en#processing_the_json_file) which could help you.

> Every value in the XML files is present in the `google-services.json` file at the locations below. If your Android project has some configuration that prevents you from using the `google-services` plugin, you can safely recreate the XML files manually using these values:
>
> **google_app_id:**
>
> `{YOUR_CLIENT}/client_info/mobilesdk_app_id`

Also

> The main result of the JSON processing is to produce two XML files which you can reference as Android resources in your Java code. Below is an example of each file:
>
> **app/build/generated/res/google-services/{build_type}/values/values.xml**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
>     <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">UA-65557218-3</string>
>     <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">1035469437078</string>
>     <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:1035469437078:android:73a4fb8297b2cd4f</string>
>     <string name="test_banner_ad_unit_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
>     <string name="test_interstitial_ad_unit_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>
> </resources>
> ```

It seems that you can get the `mobilesdk_app_id` by getting the `google_app_id` in the Android resources.

EDIT: mobilesdk_app_id can be found in google-services.json

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @gerardnimo ! Are the XML files automatically generated by the Android Project when it's built?

Comment: Yes, it should be auto-generated. The [`build/`](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules) folder is an auto-generated folder.

Comment: Thank you. How does it generate and know the Sender ID ? Does it know based on the project package name?